# Habilitando campos (array) com Jquery ao marcar checkbox

Tags: php, array

Boa tarde pessoal, mais uma vez preciso da ajuda de vocês para o seguinte problema:

Imaginem os seguintes registros do form abaixo:

```
<input  id="check[1]"  name="check[1]" type="checkbox" value="">
<input  id="campo1[1]" name="campo1[1]" type="text" value="" disabled>
<select id="campo2[1]" name="campo2[1]" disabled></select>

<input  id="check[2]"  name="check[2]" type="checkbox" value="">
<input  id="campo1[2]" name="campo1[2]" type="text" value="" disabled>
<select id="campo2[2]" name="campo2[2]" disabled></select>

<input  id="check[3]"  name="check[3]" type="checkbox" value="">
<input  id="campo1[3]" name="campo1[3]" type="text" value="" disabled>
<select id="campo2[3]" name="campo2[3]" disabled></select>

<input  id="check[4]"  name="check[4]" type="checkbox" value="">
<input  id="campo1[4]" name="campo1[4]" type="text" value="" disabled>
<select id="campo2[4]" name="campo2[4]" disabled></select>
```

Gostaria que os campos "campo1" e "campo2" fossem habilitados somente após marcar o checkbox correspondente. Detalhe, o número de registros poderá ser maior do que 4.

Vocês podem me auxiliar?

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
        var campo1 = $(this).next();
        var campo2 = $(this).next().next();

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            campo1.attr('disabled', false);
            campo2.attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            campo1.attr('disabled', true);
            campo2.attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input  id="check[1]"  name="check[1]" type="checkbox" value="">
<input  id="campo1[1]" name="campo1[1]" type="text" value="" disabled>
<select id="campo2[1]" name="campo2[1]" disabled></select>

<input  id="check[2]"  name="check[2]" type="checkbox" value="">
<input  id="campo1[2]" name="campo1[2]" type="text" value="" disabled>
<select id="campo2[2]" name="campo2[2]" disabled></select>

<input  id="check[3]"  name="check[3]" type="checkbox" value="">
<input  id="campo1[3]" name="campo1[3]" type="text" value="" disabled>
<select id="campo2[3]" name="campo2[3]" disabled></select>

<input  id="check[4]"  name="check[4]" type="checkbox" value="">
<input  id="campo1[4]" name="campo1[4]" type="text" value="" disabled>
<select id="campo2[4]" name="campo2[4]" disabled></select>
```

Segue o exemplo. Ao clicar em qualquer um dos checkbox é verificado se o mesmo está marcado ou não. E para pegar os dois campos após o checkbox utilizei a função next do jQuery.

Comment: Perfeito pessoal, as duas funções resolvem o meu problema!! Abçs

Answer (score 1):

Olá, bom eu faria coisa do tipo

```
<div class="myclass">
   <input  id="check[1]"  name="check[1]" type="checkbox" value="">
   <input  id="campo1[1]" name="campo1[1]" type="text" value="" disabled>
   <select id="campo2[1]" name="campo2[1]" disabled></select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">    
   $("myChek").change(function(){
      if($(this).attr("checked")){
         $(".myclass").find("input").addClass("lockedField"); // classe para altera a cor do elemento
         $(".myclass").find("input").attr("readonly", true); // bloqueia input
      } else {
         // Bloqueia
      }
})
</script>
```

espero que ajude! :D